# How to modify Contact Form 7 Success/Error Response Output

Tags: filters, twitter-bootstrap, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to find a way to override or filter the output of the Contact Form 7 response boxes which are shown when a form error or success message is shown.

As default, Contact Form 7 outputs this HTML when a form sends successfully:

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">
    Thank you for subscribing!
</div>
```

Effectively, I want to change the output HTML of the response to be a Bootstrap dismissable alert like so:

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none alert alert-success" role="alert">
    Thank you for subscribing!
</div>
```

I've tried scouring the Contact Form 7 documentation and looked through the plugins source code to find the filter that I think I need, but I can't get the response HTML output to change. This is the code that I've tried:

```
function filter_wpcf7_response_output( $output ){
    // Replace Success CSS Class
    $output = str_replace( ' wpcf7-mail-sent-ok', ' alert alert-success', $output );
    return $output; 
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'filter_wpcf7_response_output', 10, 1 );
```

But it doesn't appear to change the output at all... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've, for the time being, added some CSS rules for the standard Contact Form 7 CSS classes so that the response notifications are styled the same as the Bootstrap alerts. But I'm still interested to know how to modify the output with the above filter.

Comment: Ummm, why has my question been down voted?

Comment: Who ever voted to close this need a good slap up side the head. Seriously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After taking a deeper look in to this, I realised that the responses that are displayed are produced via the Contact Form 7 AJAX.

So, following the [Contact Form 7 documentation on DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/), I was able to get this working how I wanted with the following JS code:

```
/* Validation Events for changing response CSS classes */
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
    $('.wpcf7-response-output').addClass('alert alert-danger');
}, false );
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7spam', function( event ) {
    $('.wpcf7-response-output').addClass('alert alert-warning');
}, false );
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailfailed', function( event ) {
    $('.wpcf7-response-output').addClass('alert alert-warning');
}, false );
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    $('.wpcf7-response-output').addClass('alert alert-success');
}, false );
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks mate, legend!

Comment: This is good... But why use jQuery for the selector but not the event listener?.  Use it for both or neither

Comment: Badly, there is no filters on the messages displayed, so we have to take this into JavaScript. This answer is so far the only way to achieve it!

Comment: You should probably remove the `.alert-*` classes before adding a new class in each event listener to prevent adding multiple `.alert-*` classes after hitting more than one event while interacting with the form.

You can add this to chain before `.addClass()`:
`.removeClass(function (index, className) { return (className.match (/(^|\s)alert-\S+/g) || []).join(' '); })`

Also keep in mind you might still have to override styles for `.wpcf7-response-output` in your theme's stylesheet, as the plugin uses styles for that class that changes some of the bootstrap styles.

Comment: Nice little hack: Instead of adding the JS to your theme/plugin you can put it in the contact form definition (using `<script>...</script>` tags).